# Vue.js - temporarily highlight table row with transition

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on a simple view with Vue.js that does the CRUD actions and to improve UX I want to highlight the recently added/modified record row for 1-2 seconds.

However, no solution of mine seems to work. The background color is changed as expected, however, that happens without any transition.

Would greatly appreciate any hint!

Here's my component (replaced irrelevant bits with `...`):

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <h2>Sponsors</h2>
        <v-table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="sponsor in sponsors" :key="sponsor.id" :class="{highlight: lastSponsorId === sponsor.id }">
                <td>{{ sponsor.name }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <v-btn depressed color="success" @click="openEditDialog(sponsor)">Edit</v-btn>
                        <v-btn color="error" @click="deleteSponsor(sponsor)">Delete</v-btn>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </v-table>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
....

export default {
    name: 'SponsorsIndex',
    components: {
        SponsorModal,
        ConfirmationDialog
    },
    ...
    watch: {
        ...
        lastSponsorId (val) {
            if (val !== null) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.$store.dispatch('sponsors/resetLastSponsor');
                }, 1 * 1000);
            }
        },
    },
....
}
</script>

<style>
tr {
    background-color: white;
}
.highlight {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    transition-property: background-color;
    transition: background-color 2s;
}
</style>
```

**UPDATE**
I was able to achieve fade-out of the background with the following CSS

```
tr {
    transition: 1s all ease;
}
tr.highlight {
    background-color: #76b5c5;
    color: white;
}
```

However, it only fades out but does not fade-in

Comment: Could you [import](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) your project into codesandbox to create a [mcve]? What you posted is not runnable and, considering your question is mostly CSS related, this makes it very difficult for anyone to provide help.

Comment: Moving `transition: background-color 2s;` from `.background` to `tr` [should work](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/eYjdePY). If it doesn't, it means you have additional styles applying so answering the question without a runnable example is close to impossible. As a general rule, CSS related questions can't be answered without an actual runnable example. In theory, your problem could have also been caused by elements being completely replaced on re-render, but that's not the case, since the rows are key-ed, which means they're not replaced on re-render.